# bash doesn't run commands in sequential order

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I have a bash script that contains the following:

```
MY_COMMAND="MY_PWD=`pwd`; export MY_PWD; MY_PWD_BASENAME=`basename $MY_PWD`; echo $MY_PWD_BASENAME"; export MY_COMMAND
```

When I source the script from the terminal, I get the following error:

```
basename: missing operand
Try `basename --help' for more information.
```

This indicates that the commands in `MY_COMMAND` are not executed in sequential order.
What is happening here?

Comment: Why do you expect that `FOO="cmd1;cmd2"` would execute any commands?

Comment: Use a function. Do not put commands in a variable. Use a function.

Comment: @hek2mgl try it and you'll see that it does execute the commands. The question is why it does not execute them sequentially?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following line:

```
MY_COMMAND="MY_PWD=`pwd`; export MY_PWD; MY_PWD_BASENAME=`basename $MY_PWD`; echo $MY_PWD_BASENAME"
```

will **not** execute the following commands (as you may think):

```
MY_PWD=`pwd`
export MY_PWD
MY_PWD_BASENAME=`basename $MY_PWD`
echo $MY_PWD_BASENAME"
```

Instead it will expand the [*command substitutions*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

```
`pwd`
`basename $MY_PWD`
```

and replace them with their output. Since `$MY_PWD` is not set, `basename` will get executed without the required argument, like:

```
basename
```

That leads to the error.

---

Fix: I recommend to use `$()` instead of backticks for the command substitution. One benefit is that you can nest them:

```
MY_COMMAND="MY_PWD=$(pwd); export MY_PWD; MY_PWD_BASENAME=$(basename "$(pwd)"); echo $MY_PWD_BASENAME"
```

---

However, that's just the syntax fix. Generally I recommend to use a function like [@chepner suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877208/bash-doesnt-run-commands-in-sequential-order?noredirect=1#comment70936914_41877208)

*lib.sh*

```
function basename_pwd() {
    basename "$(pwd)"
}
```

Use the function:

```
#!/bin/bash
source "lib.sh"
basename_pwd
```